# Add associations from mixin without overwriting existing associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a number of classes like the below:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PreventUpdate

  has_many :participants, conditions: ...
  has_many :venues, conditions: ...
  has_many :companies, conditions: ...
end
```

I have a module that handles prevent_update logic (obj is in past, obj is banned) for the classes, and as part of that it queries the including class for its has_many associations in order to write before_add hooks to those associations.

```
module PreventUpdate
  extend ::ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do 
    self.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).each do |assoc|
      has_many assoc.name, before_add: :prevent_update
    end
  end

  def prevent_update
    #core prevent update logic
  end

end
```

The only problem is that the dynamically added and original has_many statements overwrite each other. Which overwrites which depends on where in the including class the module is included.

Is there any way that the dynamically added and original declarations can "accumulate", i.e. the module's declaration can simply add on to the original without overwriting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested, but you should be able to just do:

```
included do 
  self.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).each do |assoc|
    assoc.options.merge!(:before_add => :prevent_update)
  end
end
```

This would require that the concern `include` come after the `has_many` declarations. If you want to do the `include` before them, you could add:

```
module ClassMethods
  def modify_associations
    self.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).each do |assoc|
      assoc.options.merge!(:before_add => :prevent_update)
    end
  end
end
```

and then:

```
# ...    
has_many :companies, conditions: ...
modify_associations
```

**EDIT**

This should work:

```
included do 
  self.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).each do |assoc|
    has_many assoc.name, assoc.options.merge(:before_add => :prevent_update)
  end
end
```

Comment: I see that this does update the assoc.options properly, reloading the page, but it still does not pick up the before_add callback when the adding actually happens (I'm including the module below the original association line).

Comment: What does work but is just too ugly for production... I can add in your assoc.options.merge! method (and sorry I don't know how to format this)                                 assoc_string = "has_many :#{assoc.name}";
assoc.options.each do |k, v|;
 value = v.is_a?(Symbol) ? ":#{v}" : "'#{v}'";
 assoc_string << ", #{k}: #{value}";
end;
eval(assoc_string)

Comment: I've just updated my answer with a solution (a combination of your original idea and my original answer) that seems to be working...